# Search database with multiple keywords separated by a comma

Tags: java, sql

I have been trying for several days to write a search function where you can enter multiple keywords to output all lines that have these words stored in the respective column.
Searching for a single term is not a problem.
Here is my code:

```
private void StartSearchTagsTextKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                               
    if (evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {  
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT ID, Titel, Autor, Regal, Fach, Gelesen, Tags FROM TableDB WHERE UPPER(Tags) LIKE UPPER(?) ";  // hinter select kommt entweder ein * wenn alle spalteninhalte angezeigt werden sollen oder der jeweilige spaltenname welche angezeigt werden sollen
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString (1, "%" +StartSearchTagsText.getText()+ "%");

        rs= pst.executeQuery ();
        StartTable.setModel (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        pst.close();
        StartSearchTagsText.setText("");            
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "searchtagskey");
    }
    }
}
```

I hope someone has a suggestion.

Comment: It's English resource, please ask your question in English

Answer (score 1):

```
String searchterm1 = "Herrmann";
String searchterm2 = "Die kleine Hexe";
String sql = "Select * from TableDB where Autor like ? and Titel like ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString (1, searchterm1);
pst.setString (2, searchterm2);
```

It should work like that.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the simplest solution. If you can tell us what DBMS you are using we might be able to make it shorter depending on the system used.

First of all: `LIKE` only works with a single value for each evaluation it does. You can't separate it by commas like in the `IN` statement for example.

Therefore I'd suggest that you split the value of `StartSearchTagsText.getText()` into an array using the the `.split("DELIMITER")` function.

Then you can use a loop to add `"OR LIKE %" + yourArray[i] + "%"` to your sql String for every term you want to search for. (lose the `OR` for the first pass of the loop)

---

Du kannst mit `LIKE` nicht mehrere Bedingungen evaluieren, wie es z.B. mit `IN` geht.

Ich würde vorschlagen, dass du dir ein Array mit den gesplitteten Werten deines Textfeldes erzeugst. Das geht mit `.split("TRENNUNGSZEICHEN")`. Das Trennungszeichen musst du entsprechend anpassen. Wenn ein Komma die einzelnen Wörter nach denen du suchen willst separiert, dann schreibst du statt `TRENNUNGSZEICHEN` entsprechend ein `,` in die Klammer.

Sobald du das Array hast, kannst du es einfach komplett durchlaufen und bei jedem Durchlauf dein SQL-Statement mit `"OR LIKE %" + deinArray[i] + "%"`erweitern. Beim ersten Durchlauf das `OR` weglassen. Dann liefert dir das SELECT alle Datensätze zurück, was einem der Begriffe aus deinem Textfeld entspricht.